# Binding to Image control concatenating path to Path property - XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I am trying to use binding in a Silverlight app through XAML. I want to bind to the Source property of an Image control. The source property in the binding is the image filename like logo.jpg, and I want to prepend a relative path to the folder that contains logo.jpg. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Logo}" Width="125" Height="100" />
```

This is what I want:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=/AppName;component/Images/ + Logo}" Width="125" Height="100" />
```

Comment: So I ended up using a type converter to resolve the URI of image. Take a look at this link for details.

[Using converters for conditional Silverlight data binding][1]


  [1]: http://www.willasrari.com/blog/using-converters-for-conditional-silverlight-databinding/000319.aspx

Comment: Looks like you should post your comment as the answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I don't have enough points to post my own answer.